# GCC turn on compiler warnings for (sint64)~(sint64)(myVariable) )

Tags: casting, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

Is there any compiler flag that I can use to set a warning for the following?

```
myVariable2 = (sint64)~(sint64)(myVariable1) )
```

Comment: Other than the unbalanced parenthesis, what is it that you find problematic about that expression? Specifically what aspect do you think deserves a warning?

Comment: Maybe the compiler with just ignore the second cast, but then I want a warning to tell me that the second cast is "dead code" What do you think?

Comment: Apparently, GCC has `-Wuseless_cast`, although at one point it only applied to C++, not C. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14710